# ReactJS (with coreui): Dropdown component does not reflect the correct menu click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I was trying to build a front-end with ReactJS and coreui component. This is my code where I was trying to implement a "Dropdown" menu:

```js
class DropdownTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    this.setState({ value: i });
    console.log("clicked " + i + ", this.state.value = " + this.state.value);
  }

  renderItem(value) {
    return (
      <CDropdownItem key={value} onClick={() => this.handleClick(value)}>
        {value}
      </CDropdownItem>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CDropdown id="axes-dd" className="float-right mr-0" size="sm">
        <CDropdownToggle id="axes-ddt" color="secondary" size="sm">
          Axes
        </CDropdownToggle>
        <CDropdownMenu>
          {this.renderItem(0)}
          {this.renderItem(1)}
          {this.renderItem(2)}
        </CDropdownMenu>
      </CDropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the front-end component:

[image]

When I want is to keep a variable (let's say `state.value`) that will keep track of the menu item that I clicked. But when I run the above example, I'm seeing the above code doesn't keep track of the clicking sequence correctly. On the console, I'm getting these outputs --

[image]

For example, when I click the menu `0` for the first time, the console output is `clicked 0, this.state.value = null`, although I'm printing after updating the state (please see the `handleClick(i)` function). Again when I click the menu `1`, the console output is `clicked 1, this.state.value = 0` and so on. You get what I mean.

How do I fix this?

Note: The components `CDropdown`, `CDropdownMenu`, `CDropdownToggle`, `CDropdownItem` are from the [coreui](https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/CDropdown/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState() may set the state asynchronously. So if you want to make sure to use the updated state you should give it (the setState method) a callback to run after the state has been updated.

```
handleClick(i) {
    this.setState({ value: i }, () => {
       console.log("clicked " + i + ", state.value = " + this.state.value);
    });
}
```

For more information look at this :=> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it's giving this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I edited the code try it now.